# Dynamic content inside the collapse in VueJS 2 (vue) component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to make the dynamic content inside the Collapse button/element/dropdown. Because I will reuse it a lot. So how can I pass components inside the Collapse? For example there is some DataTable in the Collapse where I can press "+" button and another collapse would appear(I already made it) and there is another content, and I want to use those collapses, and inside of it wouldn't be a table, but for example a form. I want to Optimize it and use it for future collapses with different content.
I am using VueJS 2, BootstrapVue

Here is my CollapseSection.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="accordion" role="tablist">
    <b-button block v-b-toggle.accordion-1 class="collapse-btn" align-h="between">
      {{ selectText }}
      <b-icon :icon="visible ? 'caret-down' : 'caret-up'" class="icon"></b-icon>
    </b-button>
    <b-card no-body class="mb-1">
      <b-collapse id="accordion-1" v-model="visible" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
        <b-card-body>
          <DataTable :labels="labels" :data="data" :showAdd="true" @add-item="addItem"/>
        </b-card-body>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
//below is dynamic collapse when Click on "+" button
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <b-button block v-b-toggle="'accordion-' + (index + 2)" class="collapse-btn">
        {{ item.name }}
        <b-icon :icon="visible ? 'caret-down' : 'caret-up'" class="icon"></b-icon>
      </b-button>
      <b-card no-body class="mb-1">
        <b-collapse :id="'accordion-' + (index + 2)" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
          <b-card-body>
                some content
          </b-card-body>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CollapseButton",
  components: {DataTable},
  props: {
    selectText: {
      type: String,
      default: () => "Select",
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      visible: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```
NewForm.vue //is just an example when I call/use it collapse component(only template, cuz script is 
<template>
     <CollapseSection select-text="Collapse ">

     </CollapseSection>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "NewForm",
  components: {CollapseSection},
}
</script>
```

How to optimize it and make the methods/actions working(because in each collapse would be data and actions/methods that should be interconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used the "named slot" and it works great

Here is my updated CollapseSection.vue

```
<b-card no-body class="mb-1">
    <b-collapse id="accordion-1" v-model="visible" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end m-2">
        <SearchField class="order-2"></SearchField>
      </div>
      <b-card-body>
        <!--     CONTENT WOULD APPEAR INSIDE THIS SLOT      -->
        <slot name="content" :addItem="addItem"></slot>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-collapse>
</b-card>
```

NewForm.vue

```
<CollapseSection select-text="Select Images">
      <template #content="{ addItem }">
             <DataTable :fields="labels" :items="data" :showAdd="true">
                        <b-icon icon="plus" class="add-btn" @click="addItem(data[0].name)">
                </b-icon>
             </DataTable>
      </template>
</CollapseSection>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data after inside the collapse component is dynamic and unknown, its better to use a slot. For example, inside the CollapseSection.vue ..

```
<slot name="form"></slot>
```

Then usage

```
<CollapseSection select-text="Collapse ">
      <template v-slot:form>
          // your form goes here
          <form>             
          </form> 
     </template>
</CollapseSection>
```

Comment: In addition, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Comment: what to do with add button when I click and appears another collapse with the data? And can  I pass the inside the <template> another component, for example, list?

Comment: Of course, you can pass another component. The button depends on your implementation of how you handle the drop down and if you are using a component library .. check out the docs